# Sequelize commands not working on DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my node app on DigitalOcean droplet, but the problem is:

[image]

Upper code works correctly, but the code that uses Sequelize functions like findAll() etc. is not working. I have figured this out because my endpoint were working on localhost, but now they are not. I made sure I have Sequelize and mysql2 installed. Basically, it does not support sequelize embedded functions like findByPk() etc.

I also get this:

[image]

but I have Sequelize installed.

This is the error as asked:

Error fetching countries: TypeError: Country.findAll is not a function
at file:///root/travEM/backend/server.js:70:37

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, and not a screenshot.